# React form state mutated by submit function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios, onsubmit

I'm teaching myself React, and building a small single-page React app with an Axios API. I have a POST request that keeps on failing. Extensive use of `console.log` seems to indicate that the state of the form inputs is somehow getting changed by the submit function, though I can't figure out why. Help!

Here's the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Grid, TextField, Button, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import { FaHome } from 'react-icons/fa'

const AddItem = ({ setShowAddItem }) => {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState()
    const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`Type: ${typeof inputs} Data: ${inputs}`)
        if (inputs) {
            console.log('executing POST')
            console.log(`Inside if() Type: ${typeof inputs} Data: ${inputs}`)
            axios.post('/api/ItemModels', { ...inputs })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data)
                })
                .catch(err => console.error(err))
            setInputs()
            setSubmitted(false)
        }
    }, [submitted])

    const handleInputChange = event => {
        setInputs({ ...inputs, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
        console.log(inputs)
        console.log(typeof inputs)
    }

    const handleSubmit = event => {
        console.log("handleSubmit triggered")
        if (event) {
            console.log("if() in handleSubmit triggered")
            console.log(`Inside handleSubmit Data: ${inputs}`)
            event.preventDefault()
            setSubmitted(true)
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Grid container className="form-container">
                <Typography variant="h3">Add an Item</Typography>
                <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <TextField name="shape" label="Shape" onChange={handleInputChange} required />
                    <TextField name="size" label="Size" onChange={handleInputChange}  required />
                    <TextField name="color" label="Color" onChange={handleInputChange} required />
                    <TextField name="clarity" label="Clarity" onChange={handleInputChange} required />
                    <TextField name="price" label="Price" onChange={handleInputChange} required />
                    <TextField name="listPrice" label="List Price" onChange={handleInputChange} required />

                    <Button type="submit">
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                </form>
            </Grid>

            <Button type="button" onClick={() => setShowAddItem(false)}>
                <FaHome />
            </Button>
        </>
    )
}

export default AddItem
```

Here's a link to a CodeSandbox (which may be a bit different than what is here, as I play around with different things): [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-bas-o3r6o)

And here's a copy of the console from my most recent attempt:

```
// the last console.log from handleInputChange shows an Object with the right data
object                                    // <= that's the typeof from handleInputChange
handleSubmit triggered
Inside handleSubmit Data: [object Object]
if() in handleSubmit triggered
Inside handleSubmit if() Data: [object Object]
Type: object Data: [object Object]        // <= from useEffect
executing POST
Inside if() Type: object Data: [object Object]
Type: undefined Data: undefined           // <= useEffect triggered by setSubmitted(false)
Error: "Request failed with status code 400"
```

The logging seems to indicate that the `inputs` state mutates from a normal JavaScript object to [object Object] in the handleSubmit function, even before the `if()` and/or `preventDefault()` are called, though I can't figure out why. Here's the code of `handleSubmit()` again:

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
        console.log("handleSubmit triggered")
        console.log(`Inside handleSubmit Data: ${inputs}`)
        if (event) {
            console.log("if() in handleSubmit triggered")
            console.log(`Inside handleSubmit if() Data: ${inputs}`)
            event.preventDefault()
            setSubmitted(true)
        }
}
```

I should probably emphasize that I'm a relative newcomer to programming, and I've had to teach myself pretty much in isolation, so I'm pretty scared that there's an obvious mistake somewhere. Still, I've spent a couple of hours trying to research this, and even called a friend who's a React developer, and he was stumped too. I've tried playing around with how `handleSubmit` is called, putting it in the button, or having it returned by an arrow function by `onSubmit`. I've also tried moving around the `preventDefault`. Nothing seems to help.

I don't think this has what to do with Axios, as the `inputs` are already `undefined` by the time they get to the POST request, but I put in Axios as a tag hoping that this may be a bug Axios-oriented programmers are familiar with.

Similarly, making the POST request through Postman works like a charm.

One final thing: the backend for the project is .NET, so I'm developing on Visual Studio. I thought this might some buggy Visual Studio behavior, but running the code out of CodeSandbox creates the same bug, so unless it's some weird formatting bug that carried over, it seems to be something else, in my humble and uneducated opinion.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't put objects inside a string in `console.log()` because it will cast them as strings, always resulting in `[object Object]`. Instead pass it as the second argument or do a separate log: `console.log('Data:', inputs)`. That's misleading you and I suspect your `inputs` is fine and it's the axios call that's the problem. Also, share your codesandbox.

Comment: @MrCode Aha - I'm trying this out now.

Comment: As I thought - there's nothing wrong with your `inputs`. It's the axios call. Maybe your api requires form encoded POST data not json (axios sends json by default). Show your postman request which you said works (what headers and what POST data).

Comment: @MrCode CodeSandbox isn't hooked up to the backend, so Axios would necessarily fail, no? Is there a way for me to hook a .NET backend up on that platform? I was just using it to show where the `inputs` were going bad.

Comment: I have a couple of toughts to your code in no particular order. I would not use useEffect to call axios. It just complicates your life with the closures. Add a default data to your inputs useState like: ```useState({shape: '', size:'' ...})```. State setting is asychron. You will not see the value of a state right away as you set it. Consider using React Developer tool instead.

Comment: @MrCode I used your advice about setting an intermediate variable, and got a properly formatted object all the way to the POST, but the POST failed with 400. (I tried a few things - casting to JSON, using `inputs` instead of `{...inputs}`, but it's all either 400 or 415. Maybe this is an Axios issue?

Comment: @PeterAmbruzs I'm going to try this. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @MrCode went down a whole backend rabbit hole since I got convinced my backend was at fault, but if it is, I can't find where. I''m sending `raw` in Postman, with JSON-type content.

Comment: I finally got it. The `console.log`s were the first problem, but they were put in because of two different issues that were also causing 400s, neither of which have to do with the frontend. The data validation on the backend expected the fields in the JSON to be uppercased (Id, not id), and wanted some values in numerical, not string, format. I was able to find this by `console.log`ging a string, and copy-pasting it into Postman. Only Postman gave me the error telling me about the data types, I wasn't getting it in the console. Should I keep the question up for the value with `console.log`?

Comment: @MrCode you were the one who caught the `console.log` casting to a string - if you think the question should stay up, I'd be happy to accept an answer from you about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a summary of the comments which solved the problem:

Passing an object into the string for `console.log()` like below always results in showing `[object Object]` due to casting it as a string which lead to suspecting that the object properties are mutated when they were actually present.

```
console.log(`Type: ${typeof inputs} Data: ${inputs}`);
```

Instead, use the second argument or do a separate log call:

```
console.log(`Type: ${typeof inputs} Data:`, inputs);
```

After that it was a case of correcting the POST data properties to make sure the casing and types matched up with the backend API.